Simple Geometry of bored out volume
Given a sphere, a straight tube with circle cross section is bored out through the center.
For a separate but same sphere, a straight tube with square cross section is bored out through the center. The circle and square cross sections have the same area. For the bored-out volumes, which one is bigger, the circular tube versus the square tube?
Intuition suggests the circular tube is bigger, and perhaps the biggest for all different cross section shapes. If true, maybe there is some analytical argument to arrive at this conclusion without doing integration? This is a small part of a bigger research problem, but this small part seems to be well defined by itself.   Thanks,

Whether the tube has a circular or square cross-section, if the areas of the cross-sections are equal, will not the volumes of the perforated areas be exactly the same?

@adzetto These are not cylinders. The removed portion of the sphere is longest along the line passing through the center of the sphere and shorter as you get farther from that line.

I see. Should I think of it like a cone and a truncated rectangular pyramid? If so, there is still no difference because the cross-sectional areas are equal.

@adzetto No. You should figure out what happens where the tube emerges from the sphere. Use desmos and desmos. I did some calculations and found that the circular tube bores out a slightly bigger volume.

@Kurt G. Many thanks Kurt.  Is there a way to show that circular tube is the largest among any 2D hole shapes with the same cross section area? But thanks.

@Kurt G. Thanks for your Desmos graphics allowing (as you have done) to estimate which volume is the largest, but how about a proof ? I don't approve the closure of this applied mathematics question which is well formulated.

@JeanMarie It is just a small part of OP's bigger research project. I got the feeling OP lost interest in the details of such a  trivial special case. Ad astra but not per aspera.

@Kurt G. I understand...
